# ArangoDB Exceptions

Tags: shell, exception, arangodb

I was running commands in the tutorial, and I noticed that I kept getting exceptions that didn't seem like part of the normal operation of the shell.

Command

```
arangosh [_system]> db._update(doc, { someValue: 42 });
```

Output

```
JavaScript exception in file 'c:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.5.4/share/arangodb/js/
client/modules/org/arangodb/arango-database.js' at 789,11: [ArangoError 1200: pr
econdition failed]

!    throw new ArangoError(requestResult);
!          ^
stacktrace: Error
    at ArangoDatabase._update (c:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.5.4/share/arangodb/js
/client/modules/org/arangodb/arango-database.js:789:11)

    at <shell command>:1:4
```

Answer (score 4):

This normally happens, if you try to update a revision of document which has already been updated.

For example:

```
arangosh [_system]> d1 = db.test.save({ value: 1 })
{ 
  "_id" : "test/41839385817", 
  "_rev" : "41839385817", 
  "_key" : "41839385817" 
}
```

creates a new document.

```
arangosh [_system]> d2 = db._update(d1, { value: 2 })
{ 
  "_id" : "test/41839385817", 
  "_rev" : "41840762073", 
  "_key" : "41839385817" 
}
```

If you now try to update the original revision of the document, you get an error:

```
arangosh [_system]> db._update(d1, { value: 3 })
JavaScript exception in file '/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/HEAD/share/arangodb/js/client/modules/org/arangodb/arango-database.js' at 790,11: [ArangoError 1200: precondition failed]
!    throw new ArangoError(requestResult);
!          ^
stacktrace: Error
    at ArangoDatabase._update (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/HEAD/share/arangodb/js/client/modules/org/arangodb/arango-database.js:790:11)
    at <shell command>:1:4
```

because that revision of the document is no longer valid.

Comment: It just seems weird that the error includes a stack trace from a JS exception.

Comment: There is a full stack trace is printed because it enables you (and everyone else) to locate the actual position where the error was raised, including the full path through the program. Just imagine you called the `db._update()` from a more complex program running in the ArangoShell, with multiple update statements, nested functions etc. I think in this case a stack trace will help a lot.

Comment: Nonetheless, the exception message could be more descriptive, like `Precondition failed, document revision obsolete`.